# Magento - I need the corresponding code for magento2. This is magento1 code

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9

```
$shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareShipment($itemQty);

$shipment = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Api();
$shipmentId = $shipment->create($orderId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm bad at translations, maybe this guide here https://www.scommerce-mage.com/blog/magento-2-how-to-create-shipment-programatically.html can help you

Answer (score 0):

There isn't the same code

Only similar

https://github.com/DominicWatts/AutoShipment/blob/d5a36a6b88c2753ef484b1a17a757985672af7b5/Helper/Shipment.php#L147-L189

```
    /**
     * Mark order as shipped
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
     * @param boolean $doNotify
     * @return bool
     */
    public function markAsShipped($order, $doNotify = true)
    {
        if (!$order || !$order->canShip()) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            $orderShipment = $this->convertOrder->toShipment($order);
            foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
                if (!$orderItem->getQtyToShip() || $orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
                    continue;
                }
                $shipmentItem = $this->convertOrder
                    ->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem)
                    ->setQty($orderItem->getQtyToShip());
                $orderShipment->addItem($shipmentItem);
            }
            $orderShipment->register();
            $orderShipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);


            $orderShipment->save();
            $orderShipment->getOrder()->save();


            if ($doNotify) {
                $this->objectManager->create(\Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier::class)
                    ->notify($orderShipment);
                $orderShipment->save();
            }


            $order->addStatusToHistory($order->getStatus(), 'Order has been marked as complete');
            $order->save();


            return true;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load('1');
$convertOrder = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Convert\Order');
$shipment = $convertOrder->toShipment($order);

foreach ($order->getAllItems() AS $orderItem) {
    if (! $orderItem->getQtyToShip() || $orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
        continue;
    }

    $qtyShipped = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();
    $shipmentItem = $convertOrder->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem)->setQty($qtyShipped);
    $shipment->addItem($shipmentItem);
}

$shipment->register();
$shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

try {
    $shipment->save();
    $shipment->getOrder()->save();
    $shipment->save();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__($e->getMessage()));
}
```

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html Magento prohibits the direct use of the ObjectManager in your code because it hides the real dependencies of a class. Direct use of the create function prevents type validation and type hinting that a factory class provides.

Comment: @Dominic Xigen thanks for details, thought its just a sample code for actual implementation